# Adding react component offsets parent container height

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm encountering a weird problem: we have the exact same CSS for our layout in two different environments, but we're working on re-writing our javascript into react components - and when we add the components through react, for some reason, the container containing the react component has a greater height than its parent.

Here's a visual demonstration of what's happening:

[image: Here, the component is added via react - as you can see its height is 1618px, while the parent's height remains at 1552px]

In the first image the component (`.el-airport`) is added using React, and as you can see its height is greater than that of its container (`#maincontent`): `1618px` vs `1552px`.

[image: Here the component is rendered via the server, and the height is set correctly.]

In the second image the component is rendered on the server and has the correct height set (`1645px`). The reason for the discrepancy in the heights in the environments is that they operate on different data sets.

Here's the relevant code:

```
#maincontent {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.el-airport {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
```

`#maincontent` is contained within some more parents, which are flexboxes.

```
.content { display: flex; flex: 1 1 auto; }
```

Comment: My experience with `flexbox` in the last 6 months is that it's not yet a bug free implementation in browsers in all cases. The kind of bug you're seeing reminds me of the issues I'd had with some code.

Comment: I actually ended up just using floats and clearfixes @WiredPrairie - that solved the problem. It sucks that this is still necessary :-/

Comment: What tag are you using to load your component into?